# How is the boundary of sup F test in the strucchange package calculated?

Tags: r, time-series, breakpoints

I want to conduct a sup F test for a time-series data using the `strucchange` package, but I'm not sure how the boundary is calculated.

Here is a sample data and code:

```
library(strucchange)
data("Nile")
fs <- Fstats(Nile ~ 1, from = 0.15, to = 0.85)
plot(fs)
```

The plot shows that the red line - the boundary of the F statistics - is somewhat above 10, but where does this value come from?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUOP3.png